# Convert MIPS assembly code to C?

Tags: assembly, c

Can someone help me convert the following MIPS code back to C?

Assume that the variables `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, and `j` are assigned to registers `$s0`, `$s1`, `$s2`, `$s3`, and `$s4`, respectively. Base address of the arrays `A` and `B` are in registers `$s6` and `$s7`, respectively.

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2      # $t0 = f * 4
add $t0, $s6, $t0    # $t0 = &A[f]
sll $t1, $s1, 2      # $t1 = g * 4
add $t1, $s7, $t1    # $t1 = &B[g]
lw $s0, 0($t0)       # f = A[f]
addi $t2, $t0, 4 
lw $t0, 0($t2)
add $t0, $t0, $s0
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

Comment: What have you already come up with?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like your h, i and j aren't used at all.

Here is your code including my comments:

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2         # $t0 = f * 4
add $t0, $s6, $t0       # $t0 = &A[f]
sll $t1, $s1, 2         # $t1 = g * 4
add $t1, $s7, $t1       # $t1 = &B[g]
lw $s0, 0($t0)          # f = A[f]
addi $t2, $t0, 4        # $t2=$t0+4 => $t2 points to A[f+1] now
lw $t0, 0($t2)          # $t0 = A[f+1]
add $t0, $t0, $s0       # $t0 = $t0 + $s0  => $t0 is now A[f] + A[f+1]
sw $t0, 0($t1)          # store the result into B[g]
```

So the whole snipped could have been

```
B[g] = A[f] + A[f+1];
```

in C. Assuming, of course, that A and B are arrays of 4-byte integers.